# add constraint using different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, constraints, check-constraints

I have a database with the tables Customer and WatchHistory. A customer can only watch a movie after his subscription_start and before his subscription_end. I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE WatchHistory
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_watch_date
  CHECK (watch_date > Customer.subscription_start AND watch_date < Customer.subscription_end)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "Customer.subscription_start" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "Customer.subscription_end" could not be bound.
```

My guess is that I have to use a join, but where do I put that?
The following doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE WatchHistory INNER JOIN Customer
  ON WatchHistory.customer_mail_address = Customer.customer_mail_address
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_watch_date
  CHECK (watch_date > Customer.subscription_start AND watch_date < Customer.subscription_end)
```

Comment: I think you need a user-defined function to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a `UDF` and then create the constraint on that `UDF`.

Code sample for you (not tested so please test it out) -

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufn_check_customerwatchhistory (
    @watch_date DATE
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Customer WHERE @watch_date > Customer.subscription_start AND @watch_date < Customer.subscription_end)
        return 'True'
    return 'False'
END

ALTER TABLE WatchHistory
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_watch_date
  CHECK (ufn_check_customerwatchhistory(watch_date) = 'True')
```

Comment: The general idea does work for me, but it had to be a little bit adjusted. Thanx for the answer.